# Angular promises `all` method returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have set up a promise with Angular using the `$q` service.

```
var get = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        defer.resolve('test');
    }, 1000);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

When I call this function, it returns the expected data like so:

```
var promise1 = api.get().then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //logs test
});

var promise2 = api.get().then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //logs test
});
```

But when I use the `all` method, I get an array containing `undefined` twice.

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //logs [undefined, undefined];
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your logging handlers do return `undefined`.

Comment: `get ` function could take use of `$timeout` so that the custom `$q` will get removed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return data from callback

Try like this

```
var promise1 = function(){
  return api.get().then(function(data){
      return data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It must like this:

```
var promise1 = api.get();
var promise2 = api.get();
```

Then, types of promise1 and promise2 are **"promise"** and you can use them in $q.all().

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
console.log(data); //logs ['test', 'test'];
```

});